# Process Involved in PHP Screen Scraping

Tags: php, asp.net

Can anyone tell me the process involved n PHP Screen Scraping of aspx page using POST Request? I want to download the data from a website and save it to Database.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846850/screen-scraping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General steps, regardless of technology used on either side:

1. Download the target page over HTTP (typically using libcurl)
2. Parse the downloaded document
3. Extract the parts that interest you
4. Store extracted data in database.

That's pretty much all anyone could tell you based on the information given.

Answer (score 1):

download the file :

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

if its an xml file or json, break it into an array and then search for that value you would like using

```
$key = array_search('search term', $array);
```

this will return the key of the array you are looking for so it will be $array[$key]. but if its an html page you can easily use this function to search the downloaded page :

```
function extractStringFromString ($string, $start, $end) {

$startPos = strpos($string,$start);
$stringEndTagPos = strpos($string,$end,$startPos);
$stringBetween = substr($string,$startPos+strlen($start),$stringEndTagPos-$startPos-strlen($start));

if (strlen($stringBetween) != 0) {

    return $stringBetween;
    return true;
}
else {

    return false;
}

}
```

you can use this function like `$returnString = extractStringFromString($file, '$start', '$end'`  , $start being the start of the thing you are looking for and use $end to end the search so if you have `<div id="someID">here is some text</div>` `$start` will be equal to `<div id="someID">` and `$end = '</div>'`  and the `$returnString` will equal "here is some text".

for DB, you need to connect to DB and then use a command like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Thanks for your Ahoura.
But I should download around 1000 pages, Can I automate the process of downloading all 1000 pages or should I manually run the code on each page individually? 

Note: The Pages are being loaded basing on Two Drop Down boxes.

Comment: well you can easily automate downloading the 1000 pages but you should set the timeout on 0 to prevent the page from timing out, what I usually do is run the code and download 100 pages or less at a time. you can download the pages automatically using a for() loop IF the pages are the same and only a string or and int is different in them, but otherwise load the urls into an array and run the array inside the loop, and to split them you can use a start and an end point using a $_GET var. let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: These pages are using POST Request. So, How can I load all the URL's into an array. Ahoura, If you don't mind can I get your eMail or Twitter handle ? So that I can send you the exact details, So I think you can assist me better..Hope you understand.

Comment: hey, yea sure my twitter is @AhouraGhotbi, if you want you can inbox me your skype so we can discuss it there.